# .NET Dictionary: is only enumerating thread safe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, dictionary, thread-safety

Is simply enumerating a .NET Dictionary from multiple threads safe?

No modification of the Dictionary takes place at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, in that case enumeration is thread safe since at the beginning of a `foreach` loop a new instance of the enumerator is created with an implicit call to `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: Although the new enumerator(s) call back into the same underlying array. Although I dont suspect this too be a problem for reading only.

Comment: Kevin exactly. The key here is that no write access occurs at the time. As soon as you write to the hash table, all bets are off.

Answer (score 9):

Yes ... Well almost:

> A Dictionary<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>)
>   can support multiple readers
>   concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified. Even so,
>   enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. In the rare case where an
>   enumeration contends with write
>   accesses, the collection must be
>   locked during the entire enumeration.
>   To allow the collection to be accessed
>   by multiple threads for reading and
>   writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx))

Comment: This does not answer the question. The quoted text does not imply that purely-read dictionaries (as is the case here) are not thread safe, so the "almost" is misleading.

Comment: The first sentence of that documentation reference answers the question, but the last two sentences from the documentation quote apply to "reading and writing".  Combined with your vague "Well almost" make this confusing and ultimately misleading answer for the question that was asked.   Reading without any modifications is thread-safe.  End of story.  Most of what you've supplied just muddies the water.